# convert got request request to fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to not use node server for this demo app, the request is using `got` library like so

```
(async () => {
      try {
        const response = await got(url, {
          username: apiKey,
          password: apiSecret,
        });
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.end(response.body);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.end(error)
      }
    })();
```

On my react app the same request gives me undefined as response

```
  componentDidMount() {
    var url =
      "https://api.test.com/v2/tags?image_url=https://i.pinimg.com/736x/30/fa/a2/30faa2f81feb97c0c50a144f308292c1.jpg";
    (async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          headers: {
            Authorization:
              "Basic YWNjX2UzOGM5MhMzAyMjllYzYwMw==",
          },
        });
        console.log(response.body);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })();
  }
```

The cURL option look like this

```
curl --user "acc_e382c:c78f22290229ec603" 
https://api.test.com/v2/tags?image_url=https://docs.com/sample/japan.jpg
```

I have used this tool https://kigiri.github.io/fetch/
Not sure if that's the issue

Comment: If any of the above codes are your API key, I would edit the question and remove that

Comment: Your first request is sending a `Content-Type: application/json` header, don't see that in your second request? (But not in the cURL command either.)